# Использование deployment в webstrom для замены файлов node.js приложения на сервере

Tags: node.js, сервер, развертывание, webstorm

Добрый день.

Дописываю чужое node.js приложение на express (небольшие правки в роуторах). Могу ли я заменить файлы на сервере с помощью  deployment в webstrom без перезагрузки сервера/ноды? Если нет, то как их перезагрузить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам же себе отвечаю.

Да, нужно перезагрузить сервер с помощью команды `npm restart` в папке с приложением (или с помощью команд `npm stop` и `npm start` в зависимости от ситуации).

В этом ролике это хорошо показано (как и деплой node.js в целом):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lXVkB-yZWU